# Slugs in SQLAlchemy, Pyramid, and Python 3

Tags: python, unicode, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, pyramid

I'm using Python 3.3.1, the latest versions of Pyramid and SQLAlchemy, and I think I'm having some Unicode issues.

I have a database model set up like this:

```python
class Blah(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'terms'
    term_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = Column(Unicode, unique=True)
    created = Column(DateTime, default=datetime.datetime.utcnow)
    body = Column(UnicodeText)

    @property
    def slug(self):
        return slugify(self.title)

    @classmethod
    def all(cls):
        return DBSession.query(Blah).order_by(sa.desc(Blah.title))

    @classmethod
    def by_id(cls, term_id):
        return DBSession.query(Blah).filter(Blah.term_id == term_id).first()

    @classmethod
    def by_slug(cls, slug):
        return DBSession.query(Blah).filter(Blah.slug == slug).first()

    @classmethod
    def get_paginator(cls, request, page=1):
        page_url = PageURL_WebOb(request)
        return Page(Blah.all(), page, url=page_url, items_per_page=5)
```

slugify and paginator are functions I adapted from Python 2 code and check out ok through basic tests. I can run something like >> slugify('String text')  and get an output that looks like string-text which is what I want.

When I try to add things to the DB instead of a slug I get  or something similar and not an actual slug. I have tried various things like making the title use Text instead of Unicode, or UnicodeText. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

(On a side note, I can get it to work ok with Python 2 the way it's set up... but then the query by_slug works but only if I first query by_id. So both the term_id and the slug have to be in the URL to work properly. Not sure if that's related...likely a second question)

Comment: As far as I can tell from the code you posted, the property `slug` is dynamic and it is not stored in the database.  Therefore you cannot query it with your `by_slug` method.  You will either have to store the slug in the database in a denormalized column or query by the id instead.  I would recommend doing what you stated at the end, storing the id AND the slug in the url and then doing lookups by the id only even if you do end up storing the slug in the database.

Comment: Thank you @plantian . I had tried something like slug = Column(Text, default=slug) and had an error if I remember correctly... I'll do some digging on how to store this.

Comment: But I do have one question... why would you suggest doing lookups by id? Is this a performance issue?

Comment: Mainly it is because if you ever change the slug then the old url stops working which will lose your SEO and incoming links, whereas you can redirect old slugs to the new slug if you are using the id.  The url will work for as long as that document exists.

Comment: Also, I'm pretty sure you can't have a column with the same name as a @property, in case you were trying to have both.

Comment: Not sure if this is the most relevant place to ask, but out of curiosity how would I save the slug to the DB?